# What were John Profumo's responsibilities as the Secretary of State for War in Macmillan's government?

Tags: political-history, united-kingdom, 1960s, post-war

Although I've found that "Profumo's responsibility was the Army, and his principal preoccupation was helping to recruit and establish a regular volunteer Army after the abolition of conscription" (The telegraph http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/1512656/John-Profumo.html), it seems to me that his duties included more than this.

Comment: Would you like to make an educated guess? Actually I'm looking for someone who'd answer my question and explain to me what exactly was Profumo responsible for. Information like the one I've posted or those mentioning his "NATO responsibilities", to me, are not sufficient. I'd prefer not to make any suggestions since I do not feel an expert. That's why I'm here.

Comment: I think what @MarkC.Wallace meant was, *why* do you find this insufficient? That is, when you say "it seems" he had more duties, did you have any specific reason to think that? It would be helpful to include such information in the question.

Comment: @Yoda  The published facts are clear and precise on Profumo being responsible for the War Office. Of course, it is imprecise on *what exactly those responsibilities* were. The thing is, to me at least, OP's wording strongly implies they think the John Profumo has additional responsibility *beyond* to the army (*his duties included more than this*). This is why we would like to see such clarifications from the OP, in the question.

Comment: @Semaphore Thank you, that's actually explained your point of view in a pleasent way, I didn't think about it like that.

Comment: I was apparently more abrasive than I intended; I apologize and have deleted the comments.

Answer (score 4):

He was in charge of the [War Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Office), so ultimately was responsible on the civilian side for the Army in the same way as the current Minister of Defence is ultimately responsible for the Army, RN and RAF. So things that he would have had to answer for in Parliament would include:

- Development and implementation of defence policy.
- Annual budget, including new equipment purchases.
- Senior promotions/appointments (e.g. appointing the CIGS).
- All the other bells & whistles that any CEO has to deal with.